# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen

Tags: java, wsdl, skeleton-code

I am trying to generate a WSDL file Using the following command :
`wsgen -wsdl -cp build/classes/java/main/ -d build/classes/java/main/ -r src/main/resources/         org.example.Commands`

And I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen

Please advise
[image: What my build looks like]

I've tried looking elsewhere and found nothing similar.